# Is "ppimaintserver:~$ sudo nano 00-installer-config.yaml" the same as "ppimaintserver:/etc/netplan$ sudo nano 00-installer-config.yaml"

Tags: networking, server, systemd, netplan

Sorry for the stupid question

Is

```
ppimaintserver:~$ sudo nano 00-installer-config.yaml
```

the same as

```
ppimaintserver:/etc/netplan$ sudo nano 00-installer-config.yaml
```

My spider sense tells me this is a file in two different locations....

I will have another question about my network static IP soon

Comment: Nope, they are different ... Your spider sense is right about locations but add to that different files as well regardless of the identical names.

Comment: This isn't about Spider Sense, but about file paths. The path `~` is an alias to your home directory (maybe `/home/rob`). The path `/etc/netplan` is that directory.